# Meagre subset of complete metric space has no dense subset?

Tags: metric-spaces, baire-category

I was assigned the exercise to show that in Complete metric space $(X,d)$ , if $G$ is a dense $G_{\delta}-$set, then $G$ is not meager. I proceeded as follows:

If $G \subseteq \bigcup \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n$, where int$(\overline{E_n})=\emptyset$ for all $n$, then
$$X=\overline{G}\subseteq \overline{\bigcup \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n} \subseteq \bigcup \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \overline{E_n},$$
so $$X=\bigcup \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \overline{E_n}.$$
But since $X$ is complete, one of the consequences of the Baire category theorem is that int$(\overline{E_N}) \ne \emptyset $ for some $N\in \mathbb{N}$, a contradiction. Thus $G$ is not meager.

But this argument doesn't seem to rely on the fact that $G$ is a $G_\delta-$set at all, only that $G$ is dense. Does this mean that a meager set cannot have a dense subset, or have a commited an error somewhere?

Comment: The final inclusion in the first line does not hold generally. Think $E_n=\{q_n\}$ where $q_n, n \in \Bbb N$ enumerates $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Ahh. Your're right. I mixed up the statement for arbitrary intersections. Thanks : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So $G = \bigcap_n O_n$ where all $O_n$ are open. As $G$ is dense, all $O_n$ are open and dense and so $X\setminus O_n$ is closed and nowhere dense.

Note that $$X= G \cup (X\setminus G) = G \cup \bigcup_n (X\setminus O_n)$$

So if $G$ were meagre, so would $X$ be as a union of two meagre sets.
But this contradicts the Baire theorem as $X$ is complete (if $X=\bigcup_n E_n$ where all $E_n$ are closed and nowhere dense, none of them has any interior while the interior of $X$ is $X$..).